# Weird apache virtual host problem

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm using XAMPP on Windows and I'm trying to set up a virtual site on 8080 port. I'm using the following conf:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site2/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

In site2 I have files...

`site2/img/profile_pic.png` and `site2/icons/led/map.png`

I can open the first one in my browser using the `http://localhost:8080/img/profile_pic.png` but the second one returns 404 when I try to open it (`http://localhost:8080/icons/led/map.png`)

The funny thing is that when I enter `http://localhost:8080/icons` it list the folder `c:\xampp\apache\icons`

Whats happening here?

Comment: Do you have anything in the Apache logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the httpd.conf config file, you will probably find a default  directive defining a link to c:\xampp\apache\icons

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: I managed to figure it out on my own... but thanks man! :)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual hosting expects that you use the domain name in your request.  For example:

http://localhost:8080/whatever

is just going to try and serve up the default site.

You need to set servername to the domain name of the site.  For example "domain1.com" and "domain2.com".

You should set your hosts file (for testing) to:

```
127.0.0.1 domain1.com
127.0.0.1 domain2.com
```

and then go to each site in your browser like so:

http://domain1.com/test/file.bmp

http://domain2.com:8080/test/otherfile.bmp

Comment: Also the point of virtual domains is to have more than one address on a single port.  So is there any reason you are specifying port 8080 for the second domain as opposed to having both on 80?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because it works for /img/profile_pic.png but not for /icons/led/map.png... Why is it working for the first case then?

Comment: I want to test my site from the root directory... I cant relocate xampp because I need phpAdmin. Also, I want it to be accessible from the internet... it all done on my computer...

Comment: I'm think your config is partially working because you each site ends up being the default for it's respective port number.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

Comment: The default host in my experience will be the first virtual host that uses the defined IP:PORT combination.  Given that site two is the first localhost:8080 and http://localhost:8080/img/profile_pic.png loads, modifying the hosts file isn't needed.

Comment: Sure, but why even use VirtualHost then?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways... I found the source of my problem... The configuration was correct, the problem was with an alias defined somewhere in the default configuration used to display icons for directory listings... The alias was for `/icons/` the same directory I use... so, mistery solved :)